# Multiple break in and out calculation sql-server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I would like to calculate Multiple in and out time group by date.

Below is the current table data

```
userid  checktime
2336    2018-11-01 08:28:20.000
2336    2018-11-01 13:27:18.000
2336    2018-11-01 13:31:12.000
2336    2018-11-01 18:03:57.000
2336    2018-11-04 07:59:09.000
2336    2018-11-04 13:10:58.000
2336    2018-11-04 13:17:46.000
2336    2018-11-04 17:58:03.000
2336    2018-11-05 08:08:07.000
2336    2018-11-05 13:10:13.000
2336    2018-11-05 13:14:12.000
2336    2018-11-05 17:58:58.000
2336    2018-11-05 17:59:02.000
2336    2018-11-06 07:40:51.000
2336    2018-11-06 13:09:48.000
2336    2018-11-06 13:14:30.000
2336    2018-11-06 17:55:07.000
2336    2018-11-07 07:53:18.000
2336    2018-11-07 13:49:19.000
2336    2018-11-07 13:53:16.000
2336    2018-11-07 18:02:12.000
2336    2018-11-08 07:45:14.000
2336    2018-11-08 13:18:28.000
2336    2018-11-08 13:21:59.000
2336    2018-11-08 18:00:04.000
```

Expected result of the query

```
UserID  Date       timein1 timeout1 timein2 timeout2 timein3 timeout3
2336    1-Nov-18    8:28    13:27   13:31   18:03       
2336    4-Nov-18    7:59    13:10   13:17   17:58       
2336    5-Nov-18    8:08    13:10   13:14   17:58     17:59
```

Created Query with the help of Gordon logic

```
`DECLARE @EMPID AS VARCHAR(50) = '101356'
DECLARE @CHECKTIME AS DATE ='11-01-2018'
DECLARE @CHECKTIME2 AS DATE = '11-20-2018'
select convert(varchar,checkdate,6) as DAYDATE,
       DAYPART,
       CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,(MIN(thetime)),(MAX(thetime))) = 0 AND (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'08:45:00',(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), MIN(thetime), 108)))) > 240 OR (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'08:45:00',(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), MIN(thetime), 108)))) < 0 THEN ' '
       ELSE (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'08:30:00',(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), MIN(thetime), 108)))) END AS LATETIMEIN,
       CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,(MIN(thetime)),(MAX(thetime))) = 0 AND (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'08:30:00',(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), MIN(thetime), 108)))) > 240 THEN ' '
       ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), MIN(thetime), 108) END AS TIMEIN2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then thetime  end) as BreakOut1,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then thetime end) as BreakIn1,
       CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,(MIN(thetime)),(MAX(thetime))) = 0 AND (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), MAX(thetime), 108)),'18:00:00')) > 240 THEN ' '
       ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), MAX(thetime), 108) END AS TIMEOUT2,       
       CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,(MIN(thetime)),(MAX(thetime))) = 0 AND (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), MAX(thetime), 108)),'18:00:00')) > 240 OR (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), MAX(thetime), 108)),'18:00:00')) < 0 THEN ' '
       ELSE (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), MAX(thetime), 108)),'18:00:00')) END AS EARLYTIMEOUT,
       (convert(varchar(30), (datediff(mi, (MIN(thetime)), (MAX(thetime))) / 60)) + ':' + convert(varchar(30), (datediff(mi, (MIN(thetime)), (MAX(thetime))) % 60))) As WORKhrs,
       DATEDIFF(mi,(MIN(thetime)),(MAX(thetime))) as WRSMIN,
       Remarks
from 
(select 
       convert(date,d.Caldate) as checkdate,
       SUBSTRING(DATENAME(DW,CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),D.Caldate,106)),1,3) AS DAYPART,
       cast(convert(varchar(20),c.checktime,108)as varchar) as thetime,
       D.Holiday as Remarks,
       row_number() over (partition by c.userid, convert(date, c.checktime) order by c.checktime) as seqnum
       FROM Calender AS D
       CROSS JOIN USERINFO AS E
       LEFT OUTER JOIN CHECKINOUT AS C ON (E.USERID = C.USERID AND CONVERT(VARCHAR,C.CHECKTIME,5)=CONVERT(VARCHAR,D.CALDATE,5) )
       RIGHT JOIN Employee AS X ON E.BADGENUMBER=X.EmployeeID OR E.BADGENUMBER=X.Badgenumber
       WHERE X.EmployeeID=@EMPID AND D.Caldate >= @CHECKTIME AND D.Caldate <= @CHECKTIME2
     ) t
group by checkdate,DAYPART,Remarks`
```

Output is

DAYDATE DAYPART LATETIMEIN  TIMEIN2 BreakOut1   BreakIn1    TIMEOUT2    EARLYTIMEOUT    WORKhrs WRSMIN  Remarks
01 Nov 18   Thu 24  08:54:59    17:27:30    NULL    17:27:30    33  8:33    513 NULL
02 Nov 18   Fri NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
03 Nov 18   Sat NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
04 Nov 18   Sun 18  08:48:43    NULL    NULL        0   0:0 0   NULL
05 Nov 18   Mon 21  08:51:45    18:23:19    NULL    18:23:19    0   9:32    572 NULL
06 Nov 18   Tue 19  08:49:45    18:27:15    NULL    18:27:15    0   9:38    578 NULL
07 Nov 18   Wed 28  08:58:16    18:21:30    NULL    18:21:30    0   9:23    563 NULL
08 Nov 18   Thu 0   08:42:52    18:13:03    NULL    18:13:03    0   9:31    571 NULL
09 Nov 18   Fri NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
10 Nov 18   Sat NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
11 Nov 18   Sun 48  09:18:30    19:01:48    NULL    19:01:48    0   9:43    583 NULL
12 Nov 18   Mon 0   08:38:51    18:24:08    NULL    18:24:08    0   9:46    586 NULL
13 Nov 18   Tue 0   08:35:27    18:02:17    20:07:09    20:07:09    0   11:32   692 NULL
14 Nov 18   Wed 30  09:00:54    18:12:38    NULL    18:12:38    0   9:12    552 NULL
15 Nov 18   Thu 0   08:08:50    18:29:32    NULL    18:29:32    0   10:21   621 NULL
16 Nov 18   Fri NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
17 Nov 18   Sat NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
18 Nov 18   Sun NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    Birthday of Prophet Mohammad (PBUH)
19 Nov 18   Mon 23  08:53:35    18:08:07    NULL    18:08:07    0   9:15    555 NULL
20 Nov 18   Tue 29  08:59:02    18:47:33    NULL    18:47:33    0   9:48    588 NULL

Comment: please show how does the expected result looks like

Comment: Hi Squirrel thanks for looking in my question below is the output i am trying to achieve UserID Date timein1 timeout1 timein2 timeout2 timein3 timeout3
2336 1-Nov-18 8:28 13:27 13:31 18:03  
2336 4-Nov-18 7:59 13:10 13:17 17:58  
2336 5-Nov-18 8:08 13:10 13:14 17:58 17:59

Comment: There is no any flag column to specify which is IN and OUT

Comment: no there is none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have at most 3 pairs of columns, you can just use conditional aggregation:

```
select userid, checkdate,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then thetime end) as timein1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then thetime end) as timeout1,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then thetime end) as timein2,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then thetime end) as timeout2,
       max(case when seqnum = 5 then thetime end) as timein3,
       max(case when seqnum = 6 then thetime end) as timeout3
from (select t.*,
             convert(date, checktime) as checkdate,
             cast(checktime as time) as thetime,
             row_number() over (partition by userid, convert(date, checktime) order by checktime) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by userid, checkdate
order by userid, checkdate;
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot Gordon pointing me to right direction thanks i will post the outcome soon.

Answer (score 0):

you can use PIVOT for your need. Also, it seems your times specific for each days. So you need to find the time column names dynamically. I have prepared some queries with your needs, you can use it:

```
DROP TABLE #UserCheck
CREATE TABLE #UserCheck
(
    userid      INT
    ,checktime  DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO #UserCheck
VALUES
(2336,'2018-11-01 08:28:20.000')
,(2336,'2018-11-01 13:27:18.000')
,(2336,'2018-11-01 13:31:12.000')
,(2336,'2018-11-01 18:03:57.000')
,(2336,'2018-11-04 07:59:09.000')
,(2336,'2018-11-04 13:10:58.000')
,(2336,'2018-11-04 13:17:46.000')
,(2336,'2018-11-04 17:58:03.000')
,(2336,'2018-11-05 08:08:07.000')
,(2336,'2018-11-05 13:10:13.000')
,(2336,'2018-11-05 13:14:12.000')
,(2336,'2018-11-05 17:58:58.000')
,(2336,'2018-11-05 17:59:02.000')
,(2336,'2018-11-06 07:40:51.000')
,(2336,'2018-11-06 13:09:48.000')
,(2336,'2018-11-06 13:14:30.000')
,(2336,'2018-11-06 17:55:07.000')
,(2336,'2018-11-07 07:53:18.000')
,(2336,'2018-11-07 13:49:19.000')
,(2336,'2018-11-07 13:53:16.000')
,(2336,'2018-11-07 18:02:12.000')
,(2336,'2018-11-08 07:45:14.000')
,(2336,'2018-11-08 13:18:28.000')
,(2336,'2018-11-08 13:21:59.000')
,(2336,'2018-11-08 18:00:04.000');

drop table #temp; 
SELECT  userid
        ,cast(checktime as date) [CheckDate]
        ,'timein'+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY userid,cast(checktime as date) ORDER BY userid,cast(checktime as date)) AS varchar) AS Seq
        ,cast(checktime as time)  [CheckTime] 
INTO #Temp
FROM #UserCheck

DECLARE @DynamicColumns VARCHAR (MAX)
DECLARE @SQLString      VARCHAR (MAX)

   SET @DynamicColumns=STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Seq) 
                    from  #Temp  
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');


SET @SQLString='
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (   SELECT * 
        FROM #Temp
    ) Temp
    PIVOT 
        (
            MAX(CheckTime)
            FOR Seq in ('+@DynamicColumns+')
        ) P'

EXEC(@SQLString)
```

Comment: But O/p needs both TimeIn AND TimeOut Columns to be showed dynamically

Comment: @Zeki Gumus, thanks for the query i will try to use the logic with dynamic data and let you know what is the outcome.